# Como somar valores de listas de listas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho uma lista de listas, e queria somar os vários valores para o indice 3 de cada lista, mas só se nesta lista estiver uma determinada string. Como posso fazer?

Por exemplo eu tenho esta lista:

```
[['ALABAMA', 'Abbeville', 2645, 11, 63], ['ALABAMA', 'Adamsville', 4481, 19, 321], ['ALABAMA', 'Addison', 744, 1, 25], ['ALABAMA', 'Alabaster', 31170, 44, 640], ['ALABAMA', 'Alexander City', 14692, 119, 661], ['ALABAMA', 'Aliceville', 2419, 7, 48], ['ALABAMA', 'Andalusia', 9079, 34, 491], ['ALABAMA', 'Anniston', 22648, 461, 1988], ['ALABAMA', 'Arab', 8295, 32, 640], ['ALABAMA', 'Ardmore', 1304, 2, 31], ['ALABAMA', 'Arley', 353, 3, 27], ['ALABAMA', 'Ashford', 2177, 2, 54], ['ALABAMA', 'Ashland', 1926, 9, 63],['ARIZONA', 'Chandler', 248718, 575, 5900], ['ARIZONA', 'Chino Valley', 10850, 50, 207], ['ARIZONA', 'Clarkdale', 4090, 5, 51], ['ARIZONA', 'Clifton', 3499, 11, 42], ['ARIZONA', 'Coolidge', 11820, 66, 662], ['ARIZONA', 'Cottonwood', 11285, 44, 401], ['ARIZONA', 'Eagar', 5034, 15, 106]]
```

E o enunciado diz: Determinar o nome do estado com mais casos de criminalidade violenta (corresponde ao indice 3).

Comment: E qual foi a sua dificuldade? A resposta "nem consegui começar" não é válida, pois isso só mostra que deverá revisar o conteúdo estudado antes de tentar novamente. Por favor, edite sua pergunta, adicione o código que tentou fazer e explique o que não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sum), veja só:

```
lst = [['ALABAMA', 'Abbeville', 2645, 11, 63], ['ALABAMA', 'Adamsville', 4481, 19, 321], ['ALABAMA', 'Addison', 744, 1, 25], ['ALABAMA', 'Alabaster', 31170, 44, 640], ['ALABAMA', 'Alexander City', 14692, 119, 661], ['ALABAMA', 'Aliceville', 2419, 7, 48], ['ALABAMA', 'Andalusia', 9079, 34, 491], ['ALABAMA', 'Anniston', 22648, 461, 1988], ['ALABAMA', 'Arab', 8295, 32, 640], ['ALABAMA', 'Ardmore', 1304, 2, 31], ['ALABAMA', 'Arley', 353, 3, 27], ['ALABAMA', 'Ashford', 2177, 2, 54], ['ALABAMA', 'Ashland', 1926, 9, 63],['ARIZONA', 'Chandler', 248718, 575, 5900], ['ARIZONA', 'Chino Valley', 10850, 50, 207], ['ARIZONA', 'Clarkdale', 4090, 5, 51], ['ARIZONA', 'Clifton', 3499, 11, 42], ['ARIZONA', 'Coolidge', 11820, 66, 662], ['ARIZONA', 'Cottonwood', 11285, 44, 401], ['ARIZONA', 'Eagar', 5034, 15, 106]]

# Todos os Estados
print sum([ item[3] for item in lst ])

# Alabama
print sum([ item[3] for item in lst if item[0] == 'ALABAMA' ])

# Arizona
print sum([ item[3] for item in lst if item[0] == 'ARIZONA' ])
```

Saída:

```
1510
744
766
```

Para se determinar qual é o estado mais violento, você pode implementar algo como:

```
lst = [['ALABAMA', 'Abbeville', 2645, 11, 63], ['ALABAMA', 'Adamsville', 4481, 19, 321], ['ALABAMA', 'Addison', 744, 1, 25], ['ALABAMA', 'Alabaster', 31170, 44, 640], ['ALABAMA', 'Alexander City', 14692, 119, 661], ['ALABAMA', 'Aliceville', 2419, 7, 48], ['ALABAMA', 'Andalusia', 9079, 34, 491], ['ALABAMA', 'Anniston', 22648, 461, 1988], ['ALABAMA', 'Arab', 8295, 32, 640], ['ALABAMA', 'Ardmore', 1304, 2, 31], ['ALABAMA', 'Arley', 353, 3, 27], ['ALABAMA', 'Ashford', 2177, 2, 54], ['ALABAMA', 'Ashland', 1926, 9, 63],['ARIZONA', 'Chandler', 248718, 575, 5900], ['ARIZONA', 'Chino Valley', 10850, 50, 207], ['ARIZONA', 'Clarkdale', 4090, 5, 51], ['ARIZONA', 'Clifton', 3499, 11, 42], ['ARIZONA', 'Coolidge', 11820, 66, 662], ['ARIZONA', 'Cottonwood', 11285, 44, 401], ['ARIZONA', 'Eagar', 5034, 15, 106]]

def obterEstadoMaisViolento( lst ):
    d = {}
    for i in lst:
        if( i[0] in d ):
            d[ i[0] ] = d[ i[0] ] + i[3]
        else:
            d[ i[0] ] = i[3]
    return max( d, key=d.get )

print( obterEstadoMaisViolento( lst ) )
```

Saída:

```
ARIZONA
```

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que você já possui os dados separados por estado, podemos definir uma função que soma os índices de criminalidade:

```
def soma_criminalidade(estado):
    return sum(cidade[3] for cidade in estado[1])
```

Mas como os dados não estão agrupados por estado, temos de agrupá-los. Para isso, utilizamos a `itertools.groupby`:

```
estados = itertools.groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Assim, `estados` será um iterável que agrupa todas as cidades para cada estado. Para achar o estado com maior criminalidade, basta fazer:

```
maior_criminalidade = max(estados, key=soma_criminalidade)
```

Que gera o resultado:

```
>>> print(maior_criminalidade)
('ARIZONA', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fec56788128>)
```

Indicando que para os dados apresentados, o estado com maior criminalidade é o Arizona.

Para saber a criminalidade de todos os estados bastaria fazer:

```
for estado in estados:
    criminalidade = soma_criminalidade(estado)
    print(f'O estado {estado[0]} possui criminalidade {criminalidade}')
```

Que geraria o resultado:

```
O estado ALABAMA possui criminalidade 744
O estado ARIZONA possui criminalidade 766
```